# Changes to subscription settings on Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, subscription, google-play-console

I'm having a notification on my app on Google Play Console.

[image: Notification of Google Play Console]

I do not intend to use the subscription service in my app, despite having read both the [blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-features-to-acquire-and-retain-subscribers.html?m=1) and the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions), I don't know how I can disable the service, if it will interfere with the app's presence in the store. Can someone help me?